# Jquery code to remove item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes while selecting checkboxes i have to add the values to arrays and while unchecking i have to remove that from array.

following code am using.
but it is not deleting while unchecking

```
<tr><td class="tdstyleSelect"><input type="checkbox" name="joblist" onclick="toNfroVmps(this.id);" id="' + i + '" checked>

var toNfroVmps = function(id) {
    if($('#' + id).is(':checked')) 
        elementIds.push(id);   
    else    
        delete elementIds[elementIds.indexOf(id)]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [**Array.splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (which is, btw, a native JS method):

```
var index = elementIds.indexOf(id);
if (index !== -1) {
  elementIds.splice(index, 1);
}
```

---

You might consider using hashes (instead or a plain Array) to store your data: with each key corresponding to an ID, and value either true or false.

```
var elementIds = {
  el1: true,
  el2: true,
  el3: false
  // ...
};
```

This way adding/removing an element will be even more straight-forward:

```
elementIds[id] = $('#' + id).is(':checked'); // either true or false
```

... and you still will be able to process this hash as array, using various jQuery list comprehension functions. For example, that's how you collect ids of all the checked elements:

```
var checkedIds = $.grep(elementIds, function(el) { return el; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove array items.

```
var toNfroVmps = function(id) 
{
    if($('#' + id).is(':checked')) 
        elementIds.push(id);   
    else
    {
        // Select the index
        var i = elementIds.indexOf(id);

        // Check if the index exists, to prevent any errors that might happen
        // If exists, delete
        if(i !== -1)
            elementIds.splice(i, 1);

    }
}
```